# How to copy views from development db to test db while running rake?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I am stuck at a particular situation . 
When I run
rake db:test:clone_structure ,the test db is not copying the views that are in the development db.So is there any solution for this problem  so that I can get the views in test db also . 
I have tried using rake db:test:purge and rake db:test:clone as well. But it doesn't support me as well.

Hope I get some suggestions here ,

Thanks in Advance .

Comment: When you say views, do you mean the tables and data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the database schema format to :sql instead of its default :ruby format and see if it helps.

Just add his line to your application.rb:

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

Note: By using this option, your schema dump might become less portable.

Comment: @Chris Kimpton yes I mean tables and data. I have each view for a given table .So I must be able to add or delete data through this view .

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it myself (although I'm just about to), but the solution is supposed to be to install the [`rails_sql_views`](https://github.com/aeden/rails_sql_views) gem.